# powershell Copy-Item Illegal characters in path

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am getting the following error from TeamCity when trying to execute a PowerShell script.

```
Illegal characters in path.
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], ArgumentException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Co 
    mmands.CopyItemCommand
```

Below is my script block I'm calling...

```
$xcopyFolderBlock = 
{ 
 $destFolder    = ($args[0] | out-string)
 $sourceFolder  = $args[1]

 # See what value was passed in to the script block
 write-host "destFolder inside xcopyFolder code block: " $destFolder
 write-host "sourceFolder inside xcopyFolder code block: " $sourceFolder

 Copy-Item $sourceFolder $destFolder -force -recurse -verbose 
}
```

This is how I'm calling it...

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $web1Name -ScriptBlock $xcopyFolderBlock -ArgumentList(, $web1FolderServices, $nasFolderServices)
```

MY TeamCity log shows these values from the write-host calls in the script block...

```
destFolder inside xcopyFolder code block:  \\\s1-bridge-web1\BridgeWebServices\Prod\MileageCalculator\v1.1.31\Services

sourceFolder inside xcopyFolder code block:  \\\s1-nas-1\software_dev\build\Prod\build_user\MileageCalculator\Services\\*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Ive figured it out. The problem is in your coma in argument list, here:

```
-ArgumentList(, $web1FolderServices, $nasFolderServices)
```

because of it you had to do this:

```
($args[0] | out-string)
```

So if you do it like this, it will work:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $web1Name -ScriptBlock $xcopyFolderBlock -ArgumentList($web1FolderServices, $nasFolderServices)
```

And this:

```
$xcopyFolderBlock = 
{ 
 $destFolder    = $args[0]
 $sourceFolder  = $args[1]

 # See what value was passed in to the script block
 write-host "destFolder inside xcopyFolder code block: " $destFolder
 write-host "sourceFolder inside xcopyFolder code block: " $sourceFolder

 Copy-Item $sourceFolder $destFolder -force -recurse -verbose 
}
```

Comment: Yes! That eliminated the error but the files aren't being copied from the source to the destination. There's no error in the log. Thanks for your help.

Comment: do `Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder` to see if there's anything in the folder

Comment: i get the following error from TeamCity... Access is denied
[10:34:56][Step 10/16]     + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\s1-nas-1\soft...lator\Servi 
[10:34:56][Step 10/16]    ces\:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
[10:34:56][Step 10/16]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.Powe 
[10:34:56][Step 10/16]    rShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: Here comes your problem, you can't access network share from there. Try providing -Credential option to your copy item. The best way, however, is to temporarily map network drives and use them to copy over

Comment: I tried mapping a drive but it can't find it. I'm afraid I can't spend anymore time trying to figure this out. I will just go back to doing a simple xcopy. Thanks again.

Comment: You need to map network drive from within powershell